# Should I re-download my server data after each change?

Tags: database, server, client

I have a simple DB editor that sits on the client. When I make changes via the editor, should I re-get all my data, as some of it is changed, or can I just do a check to make sure the procedure ran without error and assume my data is the same as the server?

Comment: Do you only have one client, rather than many connected to one server? And is it a web client or an application?

Comment: It is a desktop application, and we only expect there to be one user/instance of the application. The database is also quite simple, no triggers, or anything fancy with the table

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks a bit of detail, but I think the answer is still that you have to re-get your data.  For instance:

- Some of your data might be computed columns, which depend on the data you changed, and that formula is on the server, not the client.
- There are database triggers you have to take into account, which can modify data on or after an update or insert.
- The stored procedure might not actually do an update, or might do something unexpected with the data.
- In systems supporting optimistic concurrency, your update might fail if someone else has already updated the data in the mean time.  In that case you would want to show the changed values.